# How to implement error handling when mass replacing commit author information?

Tags: git, bash, shell, tfs, git-bash

Using Git-TF to convert a TFS project to Git and keep the commit history. After conversion is done the authors need to be renamed from the TFS style "Domain\Username" to the Git style "Name Email".

The script below (source: http://ringo.de-smet.name/2013/02/migrating-from-tfs-to-git/) will not run if the first name doesn't exist. If a second name doesn't exist, it will be replaced with the last used name.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
case ${GIT_COMMITTER_NAME} in
"DOMAIN\user1") name="ProperName1" ; email="ProperName1@email.com" ;;
"DOMAIN\user2") name="ProperName2" ; email="ProperName2@email.com" ;;
"DOMAIN\user3") name="ProperName3" ; email="ProperName3@email.com" ;;
"DOMAIN\user4") name="ProperName4" ; email="ProperName4@email.com" ;;
...
"DOMAIN\user200") name="ProperName200" ; email = "ProperName200@email.com"
esac

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$name"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$email"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$name"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$email"
fi
'
```

The list of names to check against is more than 200. A Status_Access_Violation occurs when there are more than 100 domain/name lines to be filtered. When the list is split in half, both halves with execute, but not the full list. Not sure why this happens.

```
MSYS-1.0.12 Build:2012-07-05 14:56
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=0A3B3B20
eax=00000000 ebx=6D65203B ecx=FFFFFFFF edx=680A4C5C esi=3D6C6961 edi=6E614422
ebp=2275612E esp=00263808 program=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
25813 [main] sh 37608 handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
29854 [main] sh 37608 handle_exceptions: Error while dumping state (probably corrupted stack)
```

Currently trying to wrap the exports up in an if statement, but can't figure out how to check it against the current case.

How can proper error handling be added to this script and is there a way to get past the Status_Access_Violation?

```
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = .... ]
then
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$name"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$email"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$name"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$email"
fi
'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything over 16,000ish characters would throw the STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION. Solved this by automatically splitting git filter based on the current character length in each command. This filters and rewrites history X times based on splits which increases completion time. Might be a better way to do this, but this is what worked.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "DOMAIN\user1" ];
then
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="properName1";
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="properName1@email.com";
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="properName1";
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="properName1@email.com";
fi
...(properName2 to properName99)...
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "DOMAIN\user100" ];
then
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="properName100";
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="properName100@email.com";
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="properName100";
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="properName100@email.com";
fi
'
git filter-branch --env-filter '
...(properName101 to propername200)...
'
```